# Modelling algebraic data types using relational database

Tags: sql, orm, relational-database, variant, algebraic-data-types

Say you are writing an app in OCaml/F#/SML/Haskell and want to persist data in a relational database. It is easy to map product types (records and tuples) to relations, but how do you map variant types to relations?

To be concrete, how would you persist a type like the following, in a relational database?

```
(* OCaml *)
type t = 
  | Foo
  | Bar of string
  | Baz of int * int * int
```

Comment: Could you please give an example of real data you might want to store?

Comment: My first idea would be XML. You can store any kind of hierachically structured data together with descriptive meta data (attributes). But you'll need high logic to interpret this...

Comment: @shnugo As I mention I'm interested in relational databases.

Comment: Hi, you did not mention, which RDBMS you'd like to use. I'm using SQL Server. There are incredible possibilities to use XML **within** the relatioal db schema. Just define an XML column as part of a table and place there literally any data you want. Doing so, you can combine the strengthes of a RDBMS with the flexibility of XML. This was just a thought...

Comment: https://blog.typeable.io/posts/2019-11-21-sql-sum-types.html

Answer (score 10):

It seems tedious but I would create a table for each product in the sum.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id uuid PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE bar (id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
                  s  text NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE baz (id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
                  a  integer NOT NULL,
                  b  integer NOT NULL,
                  c  integer NOT NULL);
```

You probably want to store some metadata along with records of each type:

```
CREATE TABLE envelope (id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
                       t  timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
                       by text NOT NULL DEFAULT sessions_user);
```

And this suggests a foreign key constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id uuid PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES envelope);

CREATE TABLE bar (id uuid PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES envelope,
                  s  text NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE baz (id uuid PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES envelope,
                  a  integer NOT NULL,
                  b  integer NOT NULL,
                  c  integer NOT NULL);
```

And if you are even stricter you could imagine storing a `ty` column with
the name of the type and using it to construct a composite foreign key. (As
described under ["Where Not to Use Table Inheritance"](http://ledgersmbdev.blogspot.com/2012/08/postgresql-or-modelling-part-3-table.html) in the LedgerSMB blog.)

Comment: I have lately thought more about this and have a scheme involving an intermediate table to serve as a foreign key target. Some example code can be found here: https://github.com/solidsnack/pg-sql-variants

Comment: How would I store a reference to a `t`?

Comment: Store a reference to the envelope.

Comment: Was anything edited? I can't understand my own question ;)